# Custom User plugin for the group

Tags: plugin, administrator, user, user-groups

Looking for the info to have a custom User plugin but instead it shows up in the User, it needs to show up in the (User) group (backend Joomla Administrator).
There is a very good example how to develop your own custom User plugin. It adds a tab to the existing User. Used that many times.
Now I need to develop a similar plugin, but it needs to add a tab in the User group, because a setting has to apply for the whole group. Where in the plug should I make an adjustment so it will install as a plugin for the group. I assume in the .XML file but what line do I have to add or change. Appreciated!

Comment: Can you shows the example you used for user plugin?

Comment: I used this example and changed the fields to the requirements of my project. https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin/en

Comment: Do you intend to use both `onContentPrepareForm` and `onContentPrepareData` events in the plugin? If so, due to an inconsistency in `com_users` the plugin should belong to `system` group.

Comment: Yes, I use both, so if I understand you correctly, I should build a system plugin. Where in the plugin do I need to put a specific code or identifier, that the plugin will show up in tab in the usergroups?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there is an inconsistency in `com_users` which requires to create the plugin in `system` group for both `onContentPrepareForm` and `onContentPrepareData` events to work.

Change `group` attribute value in the manifest file to `system`:

```
<extension type="plugin" group="system">
```

Change plugin class name to follow `Plg<Group><Name>` convention, e.g. `PlgSystemExample`.

In plugin code change context checks to compare against `com_users.group`, e.g. in `onContentPrepareData` event:

```
// Check we are manipulating a valid form. Return early if not.
if ($context !== 'com_users.group')
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this information is what I am looking for. I will update when I succeeded with the extension. Appreciated!